# Issues creating login for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working on an assignment for uni but have ran into issues creating my login for guest book we have to create.

I have been following several videos on how to do this and I am struggling to understand how laravel works as I keep getting issues when if I programmed it in general PHP I know it would be fine. My code is bellow for my "authController". This is the server error it gives me (it makes no sense to me at all) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException. I have searched this issue online but no avail so come here to see if anyone has come across it before.

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Authentication;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('login.auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {

    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string'
            ]);
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        }

        $user_data = array(
            'email' =>  $request->get('email'),
            'password' =>  $request->get('password')
        );

        if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){
            return redirect('welcome');
        }
        else{
            return back()->with('error', 'Your details are incorrect');
        }

    }

    public function show(Authentication $authentication)
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function edit(Authentication $authentication)
    {

    }

    public function update(Request $request, Authentication $authentication)
    {

    }

    public function destroy(Authentication $authentication)
    {
//        Auth::logout();
//        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

View

```
@yield('heading')
@yield('login')
@yield('sign-up')
@yield('footer')

<header><h2>Already a member?<br> Sign in here</h2></header>

<div class="container">

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf
        <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('error') is-invalid @enderror"
               name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
        <label for="password">Enter Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password"
               class="form-control @error('error') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required
               autocomplete="current-password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Login') }}
        </button>
    </form>

</div>
```

As you can see I have begun to try and fix the issue but the error still proceeds once the login button is clicked.

All I want this to do is to log me in to the site so I can view the comments in the guest book and redirect me to the login page if I am not logged in.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated,
Ben :)

**Updated 8/11/19 00:56.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not why your form is not working but a nicer way to lay them out.

`resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="application-name" content="{{ config('app.name') }}"/>
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }} @hasSection('title') - @yield('title')@endif</title>
    <link href="{{ secure_asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    @stack('styles')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('partials.header')
        <main class="main-content">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        @include('partials.footer')
    </div>
    <script src="{{ secure_asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

`resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
            name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
        <input id="password" type="password"
            class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required
            autocomplete="current-password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Login') }}
        </button>
    </form>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        // additional scripts if required.
    </script>
@endpush
```

from your controller

```
...
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
...
```

Comment: Hi I added your code and changed app for master. Commented out the scripts and the include and now I get this error (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\Authentication given, called in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Assignment\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 377 ) any idea what it means? I've had a look online and no one seems to know how to fix it :)

Comment: Does your User Model implement `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable`?